# How to add a class to an image with smooth transitions, not clunky

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is a jsfiddle of my work so far 
I know you can't see the image but i'll try to explain what I mean. As you can see the header itself animates smoothly as i scroll down. However the image doesn't resize in a smooth transition, it just suddenly changes size. I'd like it to visibly decrease in size along with the header if that makes sense.

I have tried adding transition: all 0.8s ease; to the header-image class but it had no effect.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

HTML:

Comment: you need to set start and final height for image + define transition for it: https://jsfiddle.net/banzay52/wcb7cyrx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set the default value of `height` of the image.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {  
            $('header').addClass("scroll");
            $('.header-image').addClass("header-image-scroll");
        } else {
            $('header').removeClass("scroll");
            $('.header-image').removeClass("header-image-scroll");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
 background-color: #f3f3f3;
    color: #666;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#Page {
    padding-top: 100px;
}

header {
 background-color: #1c1c1b;
 font-family: 'Century gothic';
 font-size: 180%;
 height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #009641;
    border-bottom-width: 5px;
    position: fixed;
    line-height: 50px;
    z-index: 1000;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.8s ease;
}

.header-image {
    align-content: center;
    height: 200px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

.scroll {
    height: 80px; 
    font-size: 180%;
}

.header-image-scroll {
    height: 80px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}

#center-column {
    background-color: white;
    width: 1080px;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #888888;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

nav {
    
}

nav ul {
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
}

nav li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*display: inline;*/
    padding: 0 10px;
}

nav li a {
    color: #009641;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav li a:hover {
    color: #e2030e;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
    <body id="chesters">
        
        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                <li><a href="Menu.html">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="Burritos.html">Burritos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.html"><img class="header-image" src="http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/image/image-13.jpg"></a></li>
                <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="About.html">About Us</a></li>   
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>
        
    <div id="Page">
            
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed enim metus. Aenean suscipit imperdiet magna, vel pulvinar mauris pretium a. Nullam eleifend erat a leo sollicitudin, non consequat quam egestas. Etiam sollicitudin lectus eu nibh laoreet dapibus. Phasellus vel dui auctor tortor interdum gravida a interdum dui. Cras dapibus dui arcu, nec condimentum arcu malesuada sed. Aliquam sit amet bibendum felis, nec condimentum quam. Aenean a arcu interdum, luctus ipsum vitae, dapibus sapien.

Aenean pharetra vestibulum eros ut porttitor. Etiam fringilla augue non purus sodales feugiat. Sed at nunc et risus tempor eleifend ac non orci. Mauris a rhoncus lacus. Quisque eget malesuada risus, sed vehicula mi. Duis elementum finibus interdum. In fringilla accumsan accumsan. Curabitur sit amet tempus dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent at luctus orci. Ut eget odio dignissim, facilisis quam ut, pharetra dolor. Duis laoreet lectus nec aliquet condimentum. Ut in tellus semper, ultricies erat convallis, eleifend sem. Phasellus lacinia euismod nulla, ac egestas ipsum hendrerit eget. Sed lacinia metus sit amet sodales mattis.

Phasellus ac leo mattis, convallis dui vitae, ultricies diam. Nunc finibus arcu mauris, rhoncus tincidunt urna condimentum ut. Proin volutpat hendrerit mi, nec euismod lorem commodo in. Maecenas aliquam viverra lectus, quis euismod tortor dapibus at. Duis nec sapien non velit interdum malesuada. Duis venenatis tellus a metus varius condimentum. Integer fringilla volutpat leo ut rutrum. Aenean gravida rhoncus mattis. Nam at convallis magna. In turpis erat, mattis et lorem sed, euismod mattis nisl. Quisque eleifend convallis massa ut semper. In elementum rhoncus massa ut fermentum. Mauris pharetra libero mi, in pretium quam vehicula in. Pellentesque et lobortis felis. Suspendisse ultrices id urna sit amet semper.

Sed suscipit faucibus massa. Fusce elementum interdum leo, ut viverra libero eleifend at. In non placerat magna. Integer scelerisque molestie dapibus. Duis tincidunt diam neque, a ullamcorper libero accumsan eget. Aliquam rhoncus diam aliquet, interdum mauris sed, hendrerit risus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris euismod accumsan neque vel gravida. Aenean facilisis augue at metus ultrices, convallis eleifend lectus fringilla. Nunc porta dictum scelerisque. Morbi quis nibh vel leo sodales egestas vitae ut ligula. Quisque eu pellentesque massa. Vivamus tristique rhoncus diam, at fringilla eros fringilla at. Fusce sit amet diam lectus. Cras blandit diam id odio bibendum, et blandit risus condimentum.

Aenean porta orci id sollicitudin cursus. Pellentesque eget mauris scelerisque, efficitur odio nec, aliquet nibh. Nulla quam nisl, placerat non condimentum at, tempus non nibh. Integer faucibus ex mi, at rutrum neque auctor ut. Etiam feugiat elit lectus, ut lacinia mi rhoncus et. Mauris varius mattis metus. Integer in placerat justo, eu placerat dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non sem et ipsum dignissim eleifend vitae at massa. In quis odio in orci blandit scelerisque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam neque tortor, luctus et massa non, porta egestas erat. 
    </p>
    
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed enim metus. Aenean suscipit imperdiet magna, vel pulvinar mauris pretium a. Nullam eleifend erat a leo sollicitudin, non consequat quam egestas. Etiam sollicitudin lectus eu nibh laoreet dapibus. Phasellus vel dui auctor tortor interdum gravida a interdum dui. Cras dapibus dui arcu, nec condimentum arcu malesuada sed. Aliquam sit amet bibendum felis, nec condimentum quam. Aenean a arcu interdum, luctus ipsum vitae, dapibus sapien.

Aenean pharetra vestibulum eros ut porttitor. Etiam fringilla augue non purus sodales feugiat. Sed at nunc et risus tempor eleifend ac non orci. Mauris a rhoncus lacus. Quisque eget malesuada risus, sed vehicula mi. Duis elementum finibus interdum. In fringilla accumsan accumsan. Curabitur sit amet tempus dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent at luctus orci. Ut eget odio dignissim, facilisis quam ut, pharetra dolor. Duis laoreet lectus nec aliquet condimentum. Ut in tellus semper, ultricies erat convallis, eleifend sem. Phasellus lacinia euismod nulla, ac egestas ipsum hendrerit eget. Sed lacinia metus sit amet sodales mattis.

Phasellus ac leo mattis, convallis dui vitae, ultricies diam. Nunc finibus arcu mauris, rhoncus tincidunt urna condimentum ut. Proin volutpat hendrerit mi, nec euismod lorem commodo in. Maecenas aliquam viverra lectus, quis euismod tortor dapibus at. Duis nec sapien non velit interdum malesuada. Duis venenatis tellus a metus varius condimentum. Integer fringilla volutpat leo ut rutrum. Aenean gravida rhoncus mattis. Nam at convallis magna. In turpis erat, mattis et lorem sed, euismod mattis nisl. Quisque eleifend convallis massa ut semper. In elementum rhoncus massa ut fermentum. Mauris pharetra libero mi, in pretium quam vehicula in. Pellentesque et lobortis felis. Suspendisse ultrices id urna sit amet semper.

Sed suscipit faucibus massa. Fusce elementum interdum leo, ut viverra libero eleifend at. In non placerat magna. Integer scelerisque molestie dapibus. Duis tincidunt diam neque, a ullamcorper libero accumsan eget. Aliquam rhoncus diam aliquet, interdum mauris sed, hendrerit risus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris euismod accumsan neque vel gravida. Aenean facilisis augue at metus ultrices, convallis eleifend lectus fringilla. Nunc porta dictum scelerisque. Morbi quis nibh vel leo sodales egestas vitae ut ligula. Quisque eu pellentesque massa. Vivamus tristique rhoncus diam, at fringilla eros fringilla at. Fusce sit amet diam lectus. Cras blandit diam id odio bibendum, et blandit risus condimentum.

Aenean porta orci id sollicitudin cursus. Pellentesque eget mauris scelerisque, efficitur odio nec, aliquet nibh. Nulla quam nisl, placerat non condimentum at, tempus non nibh. Integer faucibus ex mi, at rutrum neque auctor ut. Etiam feugiat elit lectus, ut lacinia mi rhoncus et. Mauris varius mattis metus. Integer in placerat justo, eu placerat dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non sem et ipsum dignissim eleifend vitae at massa. In quis odio in orci blandit scelerisque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam neque tortor, luctus et massa non, porta egestas erat. 
    </p> 
    
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed enim metus. Aenean suscipit imperdiet magna, vel pulvinar mauris pretium a. Nullam eleifend erat a leo sollicitudin, non consequat quam egestas. Etiam sollicitudin lectus eu nibh laoreet dapibus. Phasellus vel dui auctor tortor interdum gravida a interdum dui. Cras dapibus dui arcu, nec condimentum arcu malesuada sed. Aliquam sit amet bibendum felis, nec condimentum quam. Aenean a arcu interdum, luctus ipsum vitae, dapibus sapien.

Aenean pharetra vestibulum eros ut porttitor. Etiam fringilla augue non purus sodales feugiat. Sed at nunc et risus tempor eleifend ac non orci. Mauris a rhoncus lacus. Quisque eget malesuada risus, sed vehicula mi. Duis elementum finibus interdum. In fringilla accumsan accumsan. Curabitur sit amet tempus dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent at luctus orci. Ut eget odio dignissim, facilisis quam ut, pharetra dolor. Duis laoreet lectus nec aliquet condimentum. Ut in tellus semper, ultricies erat convallis, eleifend sem. Phasellus lacinia euismod nulla, ac egestas ipsum hendrerit eget. Sed lacinia metus sit amet sodales mattis.

Phasellus ac leo mattis, convallis dui vitae, ultricies diam. Nunc finibus arcu mauris, rhoncus tincidunt urna condimentum ut. Proin volutpat hendrerit mi, nec euismod lorem commodo in. Maecenas aliquam viverra lectus, quis euismod tortor dapibus at. Duis nec sapien non velit interdum malesuada. Duis venenatis tellus a metus varius condimentum. Integer fringilla volutpat leo ut rutrum. Aenean gravida rhoncus mattis. Nam at convallis magna. In turpis erat, mattis et lorem sed, euismod mattis nisl. Quisque eleifend convallis massa ut semper. In elementum rhoncus massa ut fermentum. Mauris pharetra libero mi, in pretium quam vehicula in. Pellentesque et lobortis felis. Suspendisse ultrices id urna sit amet semper.

Sed suscipit faucibus massa. Fusce elementum interdum leo, ut viverra libero eleifend at. In non placerat magna. Integer scelerisque molestie dapibus. Duis tincidunt diam neque, a ullamcorper libero accumsan eget. Aliquam rhoncus diam aliquet, interdum mauris sed, hendrerit risus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris euismod accumsan neque vel gravida. Aenean facilisis augue at metus ultrices, convallis eleifend lectus fringilla. Nunc porta dictum scelerisque. Morbi quis nibh vel leo sodales egestas vitae ut ligula. Quisque eu pellentesque massa. Vivamus tristique rhoncus diam, at fringilla eros fringilla at. Fusce sit amet diam lectus. Cras blandit diam id odio bibendum, et blandit risus condimentum.

Aenean porta orci id sollicitudin cursus. Pellentesque eget mauris scelerisque, efficitur odio nec, aliquet nibh. Nulla quam nisl, placerat non condimentum at, tempus non nibh. Integer faucibus ex mi, at rutrum neque auctor ut. Etiam feugiat elit lectus, ut lacinia mi rhoncus et. Mauris varius mattis metus. Integer in placerat justo, eu placerat dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non sem et ipsum dignissim eleifend vitae at massa. In quis odio in orci blandit scelerisque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam neque tortor, luctus et massa non, porta egestas erat. 
    </p> 
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sed enim metus. Aenean suscipit imperdiet magna, vel pulvinar mauris pretium a. Nullam eleifend erat a leo sollicitudin, non consequat quam egestas. Etiam sollicitudin lectus eu nibh laoreet dapibus. Phasellus vel dui auctor tortor interdum gravida a interdum dui. Cras dapibus dui arcu, nec condimentum arcu malesuada sed. Aliquam sit amet bibendum felis, nec condimentum quam. Aenean a arcu interdum, luctus ipsum vitae, dapibus sapien.

Aenean pharetra vestibulum eros ut porttitor. Etiam fringilla augue non purus sodales feugiat. Sed at nunc et risus tempor eleifend ac non orci. Mauris a rhoncus lacus. Quisque eget malesuada risus, sed vehicula mi. Duis elementum finibus interdum. In fringilla accumsan accumsan. Curabitur sit amet tempus dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat. Praesent at luctus orci. Ut eget odio dignissim, facilisis quam ut, pharetra dolor. Duis laoreet lectus nec aliquet condimentum. Ut in tellus semper, ultricies erat convallis, eleifend sem. Phasellus lacinia euismod nulla, ac egestas ipsum hendrerit eget. Sed lacinia metus sit amet sodales mattis.

Phasellus ac leo mattis, convallis dui vitae, ultricies diam. Nunc finibus arcu mauris, rhoncus tincidunt urna condimentum ut. Proin volutpat hendrerit mi, nec euismod lorem commodo in. Maecenas aliquam viverra lectus, quis euismod tortor dapibus at. Duis nec sapien non velit interdum malesuada. Duis venenatis tellus a metus varius condimentum. Integer fringilla volutpat leo ut rutrum. Aenean gravida rhoncus mattis. Nam at convallis magna. In turpis erat, mattis et lorem sed, euismod mattis nisl. Quisque eleifend convallis massa ut semper. In elementum rhoncus massa ut fermentum. Mauris pharetra libero mi, in pretium quam vehicula in. Pellentesque et lobortis felis. Suspendisse ultrices id urna sit amet semper.

Sed suscipit faucibus massa. Fusce elementum interdum leo, ut viverra libero eleifend at. In non placerat magna. Integer scelerisque molestie dapibus. Duis tincidunt diam neque, a ullamcorper libero accumsan eget. Aliquam rhoncus diam aliquet, interdum mauris sed, hendrerit risus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Mauris euismod accumsan neque vel gravida. Aenean facilisis augue at metus ultrices, convallis eleifend lectus fringilla. Nunc porta dictum scelerisque. Morbi quis nibh vel leo sodales egestas vitae ut ligula. Quisque eu pellentesque massa. Vivamus tristique rhoncus diam, at fringilla eros fringilla at. Fusce sit amet diam lectus. Cras blandit diam id odio bibendum, et blandit risus condimentum.

Aenean porta orci id sollicitudin cursus. Pellentesque eget mauris scelerisque, efficitur odio nec, aliquet nibh. Nulla quam nisl, placerat non condimentum at, tempus non nibh. Integer faucibus ex mi, at rutrum neque auctor ut. Etiam feugiat elit lectus, ut lacinia mi rhoncus et. Mauris varius mattis metus. Integer in placerat justo, eu placerat dui. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non sem et ipsum dignissim eleifend vitae at massa. In quis odio in orci blandit scelerisque. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam neque tortor, luctus et massa non, porta egestas erat. 
    </p>      
    
    </div> <!-- Page -->
        
    </body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you, I have it working now. Much appreciated :D

Comment: @EthanBristow Thanks, have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, you need to add `transition:all 0.8s ease` to it, but you ***also*** need to set its initial height.

That is because the default value for `height` is `auto` and it cannot be animated.

Demo at https://jsfiddle.net/sbh5fkfx/1/

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you, I have it working now. Much appreciated :D